# How to select data of one table and insert in other table?

Tags: java, sql

I have a project in java where i want that certain data from one table (that is in Sql management studio) is selected and that is inserted in other table. So that i can access data on a jsp page from second table. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL, you can use `SELECT INTO` statements to achieve this easily:

```
SELECT Column1,Column2
INTO SecondTable
FROM FirstTable
WHERE Column3='Whatever'
```

This will copy the data from `FirstTable` into `SecondTable`.

See [This Link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) for more examples

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to iterate through the table while writing the values into an array. Once the data has been stored into the array you can re-iterate through the array but this time inserting the values into a new table.

This may not be the most efficient method, I am sure someone else will chime in if so.

Another method which does not require Java would be to use the Select As statement in SQL, see example.

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
  AS (SELECT *
         FROM companies
         WHERE id > 1000);
```

Or if you already have a table created you can do the following,

```
INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
SELECT account_no, name
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'Newark';
```